# Is my proof by contradiction that $x^2-y^2\ne1$ for every positive integers $x$ and $y$, correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Prove the following statement by contradiction:

For each two positive integers $x$ and $y$, $x^2 - y^2 \neq 1$

What I did:

Proof:

We use proof by contradiction.

1) Suppose $x^2 - y^2 \neq 1$ is false, that is $x^2 - y^2 = 1$

2) Assuming that $x^2 - y^2 = 1$, then $(x+y)(x-y)=1$

3) Then $(x-y) = \frac { 1 }{ x+y } $

4) So, $x-y$ must be an integer since $x,y\in\mathbb{Z^+}$, which also implies that (x+y) divides $1$

5) Since $x,y > 0$, $x+y$ must be equal to $1$ iff $x-y=1$. This is a contradiction since $x-y$ and cannot be equal to $1$.

6) Therefore, $x^2 - y^2 \neq 1$

Is my proof complete and correct? Please give constructive criticism in regards to it. I suspect that lines $4$ and $5$ might be a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Step 2) means that $x+y\in\mathbb{Z}^\times=\{-1,1\}$. Since, $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$, $x+y\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x+y=1$ then $(x,y)\in\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ which is a contradiction because $x$ and $y$ are both non-zero.

Step 3) and 4) are corrects but here you have another way to say it. However, step 5) is a bit unclear, at least you can say that $x+y=x-y$ implies $y=0$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a bit confused by what you tried to say about step 2)..

Comment: It's a group theory reformulation of the equality $(x+y)(x-y)=1$, but what you've done in step 3) and 4) is correct and says the same thing! :)

Comment: I'm a bit hesitant to change something in my proof for something that I don't quite get. Is my proof in its current state correct?

Comment: Yes, just make step 5) clearer explaining why $x-y$ cannot be equal to $1$.

Comment: Ok, I changed step 5) to: Since $x,y>0, x+y$ must be equal to $1$ iff $x-y=1$. So, $x+y=x-y$; this implies $y=0$ which is a contradiction.